# Where is the mistake here: 'bubbleSort' : local function definitions are illegal

Tags: visual-c++

This is my code for windows form application. Please help. My task is: Write a Windows Forms Application which enters 10 integer numbers from the keyboard. The App should arrange and visualize the integer numbers into ascending order. 
Use an array for creating a program part.

int r[10];

```
        r[0]=System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox1->Text);
        r[1]=System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox2->Text);
        r[2]=System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox3->Text);
        r[3]=System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox4->Text);
        r[4]=System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox5->Text);
        r[5]=System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox6->Text);
        r[6]=System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox7->Text);
        r[7]=System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox8->Text);
        r[8]=System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox9->Text);
        r[9]=System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox10->Text);

        void bubbleSort(int r[10])
    { 

        int temp; 
        int n=10;
        for(int x=0; x<n; x++)

{

    for(int y=0; y<n-1; y++)

    {

        if(r[y]>r[y+1])

        {

            int temp = r[y+1];

            r[y+1] = r[y];

            r[y] = temp;

        }

    }

}
```

}
label1->Text="The numbers in ascending order are: "+ r[10];

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you cannot define a function inside another function/method. Move `bubbleSort()` out of the surrounding method.